# Laravel: How top pass id to controllore using ajax get

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am trying to pass a productId to a controllor in order to show the related product properties in a modal booststrap.

I would like tho show the pop up in the main page index. This is the related route:

```
Route::get('/', 'FrontendController@index');
```

This is tha ajax get call:

```
 $("#getModal").on("click",function(){
    $.ajax({
     url: '{{url('./')}}',
    type: 'GET',
    data: { productId: 1 },
    success: function(response)
    {
     console.log('Ajax submitted);
      }
      });

       });
```

This is the request detected in the console:

```
localhost/SHOP-ONLINE/public/?productID=1
```

It seems everything is working fine. But, how can I pass the **productId value** in the controller? if I try following I cannot pass it:

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
  $productID = $request->productId

  }
```

Comment: Variables only last as long as the program runs. You can't store anything in a controller. That's what sessions and databases are for.

Comment: The URL you are showing us uses two uppercase characters for `ID`, where as your controller tries `Id`, with only one uppercase character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use the `get()` method of the `request` object.

```
 public function index(Request $request) {
  $productID = $request->get('productID');
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this :

```
public function index(Request $request) {

  $productID = $_GET['productID'];
}
```

Hope this work for you !!!